# Open ebooks in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ebooks, extract

I have downloaded e-books in both electronic publication and mobile reader. In windows a program called 7zip extracts the files. Which program will do the same in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: What type of file are they? This is usually given by the extension--a `.` followed by a few characters, at the end of the filename.

Answer (score 4):

Install **[Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/)**. It's an eBook Management program. It has dozens of plugins and features to cover pretty much any possible ebook related need, including Robust Conversion tools, as well as an eBook Extractor/Modifier.

Just import a book into **Calibre** and then right-click on it and select "Tweak Book".

The "Tweak Book" feature might only support EPUBs but you can just convert most other formats into your desired format using Calibre's Conversion tools.

**EDIT:** As of version 1.15 of Calibre, The old "Tweak Book" feature(extracting the book and presenting a folder to edit) has been replaced by a full on EPUB/AZW ebook editor. If you still wish to simply extract EPUBs into their respective parts, simply rename the EPUB file to "NAME.zip" and open them using a standard File Archive program like "File Roller" in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

I tried several different methods, then found that if I used Wine tricks, it offered to install the adobe digital edition (under install app). Then I could access the adobe digital edition, put in my ID, (after going to adobe and creating an ID), then it was just a matter of dragging the Book.ascd file onto the open pane of adobe digital edition and reading the Ebook.

Answer (score 1):

Open software center and download 7zip.
You might also want to look into Calibre, a really good ebook management software.